# JSON.stringify(data)

Tags: ajax

I have the following .ajax

```
$.ajax({

    url: urlpath,

    type: 'POST',

    dataType: 'json',

    data: JSON.stringify(json),

    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

    success: function (data) {

        alert(JSON.stringify(data));

    },

    error: error

});
```

What I am passing back is a list with 3 columns. When I do   alert(JSON.stringify(data));
it shows me the data - 3 columns and 4 rows of data. How do I go about parsing this and storing it into a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have a table with an `id="my-table"`, you can substitute your alert with something like:

```
   $('#my-table tr').each(function (r) {
        $('td', this).each(function (c) {
            // here you cycle on every td (column) of a row to populate it
            // example with 3 columns assuming this json structure 
            // {
                 "row1": [ 100, 200, 300],
                 "row2": [ 50, 200, 400 ],
                 "row3": [ 10, 300, 200]
            // }
            this.innerHTML = data["row"+r][c]
        })
    });
```

1. `$('#my-table tr')...` find create an array with your table rows
2. `$('td', this)...` apply an anonimous function on every `td` of the loop current `tr` (`this` acts as the search context for `tds`